# List of all ip address (i.e devices) present in a local area network

Tags: c++, c, node.js, networking, dhcp

I want to get the list of all IP addresses (i.e devices) present in a local area network. I don't want to use nmap, other networking tools. And also I don't want to ping each Ip address in a sub-net range and find live IP addresses? Is there any way by using C, C++?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. And explain why the tools that are expressly designed for this purpose are not good enough for you.

Comment: If you want clients to 'discover' a service you're providing, you could have a look at broadcast packages: Each client sends a number of broadcast packages, and the server sends a reply to the ip that did the broadcast. (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13427/how-do-game-clients-know-that-a-server-is-running-on-their-lan)

Comment: I want to use it pragmatically and i am unable to configure these tools so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reliable way to determine all hosts in a LAN. There are many means of guessing your neighbors, each with its own advantages and drawbacks. But you will never be sure you get all hosts. e.g you can try to ping a broadcast, but someone could not reply to the ping. So there is no reliable way to do it. There are some ways which rely on commands in a terminal.
You can try using nmap. Although it needs to install nmap:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.*
```

This does a simple ping scan in the entire subnet to see which all host's are online.

Or you can also try the following steps (Does not require installing nmap):

- Type “ipconfig” at command prompt. This will give you ip address of
  your own machine. For example, your machine ip address is 192.168.1.6
  So your broadcast IP address is 192.168.1.255.
- Ping your broadcast IP address “ping 192.168.1.255” (may require -b
  on linux)
- Now type “arp –a” You will get the list of all IP addresses on your
  segment.

You can start the arp or nmap with the appropriate arguments in your application using some toolkit.

In Qt you can use QProcess to accomplish them like:

```
QProcess myProcess;
QString program = "arp";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-a";
myProcess.start(program, arguments);
myProcess.waitForFinished();
QByteArray result = myProcess.readAllStandardOutput ();
const QString all(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

Of course you're going to have to use some "networking tools" in order to figure this out, how do you expect the machine on which you are to know about other machines otherwise?

One approach might be to query the DHCP server, but that won't reveal devices with static IPs, and so on.

Any reliable method wil involve communicating with the devices in question in some fashion.

Comment: How to find by using dhcp server? Please explain in brief

Answer (score -1):

You can use libpcap to sniff network packets in promiscuous mode on a central location and extract source IP. Challenge is identifying a central location where to put this sniffer.

Comment: This won't solve his problem, which is to discover *all* devices on the network.