# Node.js - Local network devices list

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to get list of devices connected in local area network? I want to determine if my printer is connected or not. Thanks for answers

Comment: Did you look at [List of all ip address (i.e devices) present in a local area network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24241332/218196) in the related questions list?

Comment: Check what *service discovery* methods your printer supports. Usually you can send a broadcast query to which it will respond when it is connected.

Comment: I know printer local address, can i just ping that address to determine if printer is connected? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping

Comment: Have you considered simply using nmap with/without an nmap script to get the exact output you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible Solution**

```
var ping = require('ping');
var hosts = ['10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3']; <--- printer A and B addresses
hosts.forEach(function(host){
    ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is connected' : 'host ' + host + ' is not connected';
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```